# Xamarin iOS Slider color

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a slider in a Xamarin Forms app that I'm trying to change the color of the thumb and the slider bar.  In Android it was easy to override this in a renderer, but in iOS it looks like all I can do is change the thumb image.  Is it possible to change the bar color?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `TintColor`:

```
var slider = new UISlider(View.Frame);
slider.ThumbTintColor = UIColor.Blue;
slider.MinimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.Red;
slider.MaximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.Green;
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see what was going on now... I was doing Control?.MinimimTrackTintColor, which was only allowing me to read the property, not set it... as soon as I removed the ? it's letting me set it.  That's what I get for using shortcuts... thanks!

Comment: how can I do that directly in xaml?

Answer (score 0):

I also just found a new plugin that does all of that and a lot more. It will probably be overkill for just that but if you plan to do a lot more custom stuff to controls it might be helpful.

I have not tried it myself but I looking forward to using it soon.

[XF Gloss](https://github.com/tbaggett/xfgloss)